# How to combine latest values of two streams using futures-rs?

Tags: rust

How can I implement the equivalent of [Rx `combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) with [futures-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs) [streams](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.11/futures/stream/index.html)?

I'd like to get a stream of pairs with the current value of either stream, with the latest value from the other stream. The first value would be emitted only after having one value from each stream.

Comment: What have you tried? We expect that questions [have had a lot of effort put into them *before* they are asked on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/155423).

Comment: I've checked the docs (doesn't seem to be implemented) and written my own (rather crude) implementation. This is a pretty common combinator, so I assumed I've either missed something, or there might be a quality implementation somewhere out there.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but would you mind sharing your "crude" implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Below my crude implementation. Feedback is welcome! Full setup including cargo  [here](https://github.com/marcelbuesing/stream-combinators).

````
use futures::{Async, Stream, Poll};
use futures::stream::Fuse;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    extern crate tokio_core;
    extern crate tokio_timer;
    use self::tokio_timer::*;
    use self::tokio_core::reactor::Core;

    use futures::Stream;
    use std::time::Duration;

    use zip_latest::zip_latest;

    #[test]
    /// Combine two timer streams that produce values independent of each other
    /// Output
    /// ```
    ///    Tuple (Some(1), None)
    ///    Tuple (Some(2), None)
    ///    Tuple (Some(3), None)
    ///    Tuple (Some(4), None)
    ///    Tuple (Some(5), Some(1))
    ///    Tuple (Some(6), Some(1))
    ///    Tuple (Some(7), Some(1))
    ///    Tuple (Some(8), Some(1))
    ///    Tuple (Some(9), Some(1))
    ///    Tuple (Some(10), Some(2))
    /// ```
    ///
    fn combine_two_timer_streams() {
        let mut a_counter = 0;
        let mut b_counter = 0;

        let a = Timer::default()
            .interval(Duration::from_millis(1000))
            .map(|_| {
                a_counter += 1;
                a_counter
            })
            // We'll stop the stream after 10 loops
            .take_while(|x| Ok(x <= &10));
        let b = Timer::default().interval(Duration::from_millis(5000)).map(
            |_| {
                b_counter += 1;
                b_counter
            },
        );

        let zl = zip_latest(a, b).for_each(|tuple| {
            println!("Tuple {:?}", tuple);
            Ok(())
        });

        let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
        core.run(zl).unwrap();
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
/// get at most one error at a time.
#[must_use = "streams do nothing unless polled"]
pub struct ZipLatest<S1: Stream, S2: Stream> {
    stream1: Fuse<S1>,
    stream2: Fuse<S2>,
    queued1: Option<S1::Item>,
    queued2: Option<S2::Item>,
}

///
/// Combines the latest output of two streams.
/// It will produce a new tuple everytime any of the streams produces a new value.
/// The stream will produce `Option::None` values for streams that have not yet produced a value.
///
pub fn zip_latest<S1, S2, T1: Clone, T2: Clone>(stream1: S1, stream2: S2) -> ZipLatest<S1, S2>
where
    S1: Stream<Item = T1>,
    S2: Stream<Item = T2, Error = S1::Error>,
{
    ZipLatest {
        stream1: stream1.fuse(),
        stream2: stream2.fuse(),
        queued1: None,
        queued2: None,
    }
}

impl<S1, S2, T1: Clone, T2: Clone> Stream for ZipLatest<S1, S2>
where
    S1: Stream<Item = T1>,
    S2: Stream<Item = T2, Error = S1::Error>,
{
    type Item = (Option<S1::Item>, Option<S2::Item>);
    type Error = S1::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {

        match (self.stream1.poll()?, self.stream2.poll()?) {
            (Async::Ready(None), _) => Ok(Async::Ready(None)),
            (_, Async::Ready(None)) => Ok(Async::Ready(None)),
            (Async::Ready(Some(item1)), Async::Ready(Some(item2))) => {
                self.queued1 = Some(item1);
                self.queued2 = Some(item2);
                Ok(Some((self.queued1.clone(), self.queued2.clone())).into())
            },
            (Async::Ready(Some(item1)), Async::NotReady) => {
                self.queued1 = Some(item1);
                Ok(Some((self.queued1.clone(), self.queued2.clone())).into())
            },
            (Async::NotReady, Async::Ready(Some(item2))) => {
                self.queued2 = Some(item2);
                Ok(Some((self.queued1.clone(), self.queued2.clone())).into())
            },
            (Async::NotReady, Async::NotReady) => Ok(Async::NotReady)
        }
    }
}
````

Answer (score 2):

How about this (in futures-0.3)

```
futures::stream::select(
    st1.map(Either::Left),
    st2.map(Either::Right),
).fold((None, None), |(l, r), either|async move{
    let ret = match either {
        Either::Left(l) => (Some(l), r),
        Either::Right(r) => (l, Some(r)),
    };
    println!("{:?}", ret);
    ret
})
```

example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38827437b5227cfbf753062f727f2d0b

Answer (score 0):

How about the `zip` [method](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.11/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.zip) of the `Stream` trait?

Comment: The linked documentation for `combineLatest` says *The `CombineLatest` operator behaves in a similar way to `Zip`, but ...*, so I'd expect that `zip` is not appropriate.

Comment: `zip` only produces a (combined) value when both source streams have produced a value. What I'm looking for would always produce a value combining any value polled from one of the source streams with the latest value from the other stream. This does require each source stream to produce at least one value, and also implies the source stream items need to implement `Clone`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, my mistake. I guess you have to go with your own implementation...